# open a new tab with the same form data filled

Tags: javascript, html

I used Django to develop a web app.
In one page there's a form, once filled, a duplicate button should open a new tab of the page with the same data filled.

I already finished the new tab js function, but I do not know how to make the form in new tab filled with the data in previous tab(the same isbn filled in previous tab in my case).

```
 <form>
 <label>  iSBN:                                </label>          <input type="text" id="iSBN" name="iSBN"><br>
  </form>
      <button onclick="Duplicate()">Duplicate</button><br>

{% endblock %}
<script>
    {% block script %}
    function goBack() {
          window.history.back();
        }
    function Duplicate(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Duplicate Copy for editing";
    window.open(
    '/new-content-checklist/',
    '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
     );
    }

    {% endblock %}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from [url parameters](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6277564?hl=en) and in another tab you can then access url parameters and fill the form like this.

```
// const url = new URL(window.location);

const url = new URL('http://example.com/new-form.html?isbn=12345')
const previousData = url.searchParams.get('isbn')
console.log(previousData)
//output: 12345
```

A working demo code: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sudarshanrai/cvau2g17?isbn=12345)

**In short:**

```
const data = new URL(window.location).searchParams.get('isbn')
```